# How to return the _timestamp field parsed to a date format in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm looking for a way to return the elasticsearch's field _timestamp in a date format, like YYYY-MM-dd, but always when I make a query on elastic, the _timestamp is returned in miliseconds. Could someone help me?

This is how I'm filling my mapping:

```
"_timestamp": {
            "enabled": true,
            "store": true,
            "path": "_timestamp",
            "type": "string",
            "format": "YYYY-MM-dd"
        }
```

When I make a query, the timestamp is returned like bellow:

```
 "fields" : {
        "_timestamp" : 1446813466342
      }
```

As you can see, I put the format that i wish on the _timestamp field, but it isn't working and I have no idea why...